# Tsql row manipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got two table with the same structure. 1,2,3 and a,b,c ... are rows.

```
T1  T2      
1   a                   
2   b           
3   c       
    d       
    e
```

I need a result like this

```
T3
1
a
1
b
1
c
1
d
1
e
2
a
2
b
2
c
2
d
2
e
3
a
3
b
3
c
3
d
3
e
```

Comment: You need it in that order?

Comment: yes, i need in that order

Comment: What's the goal then? Basically you're looking for a cartesian product of those two columns?

Comment: Does T3 only have one column and there are 5 rows containing the value `1`, 5 with the value `2`, etc.? Or does it have 2 columns, with rows `1, a`, `1, b`, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Using a `cross join` will give you all the permutations. Just stick that in a cte and use the `union all` set operator to get them in a single column:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT     t1.col AS c1, t2.col AS c2
    FROM       t1
    CROSS JOIN t2
)
SELECT c1
FROM   cte
UNION ALL
SELECT c2
FROM   cte
```

Comment: +1, noting that the order won't necessarily be preserved. (and `UNINON` :)

Comment: @StuartLC fixed that typo, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cteAllColumns as (
select col1 as col
    from YourTable
union
select col2 as col
    from YourTable
)
select c1.col, c2.col 
from cteAllColumns c1 
    cross join cteAllColumns c2 
where c1.col < c2.col
order by c1.col, c2.col
```

Comment: this will produce two columns.

Comment: Agreed My Mistake...:( Thanks PeterRing .. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will preserve the ordering of the combinations during the projection into a single column:

```
select value
from t1 cross join t2
unpivot ( 
 value 
 for attribute in (Name1, Name2)
) unpvt;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9dbba/1)